# How to get Key from multiple grouped data viewbag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda, viewbag

**Controller**

I have data grouped by 2 fields

```
lst = db.Database.SqlQuery<GridReportViewModel>(sqlquery).ToList();
Viewbag.DataGrid = lst.GroupBy(x => new { x.PosisiJabatanId, x.AplikasiId });
```

**View**

How to get the Key from grouped data

```
@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var item in @ViewBag.DataGrid)
{
    @:<tr>
        <td>@i</td>
        @*<td>@item.Key.PosisiJabatanId</td>*@ @*ERROR*@
        foreach (GridReportViewModel item2 in @item)
        {
            <td>@item2.NilaiKolom</td>
        }
        i = i + 1;
    @:</tr>
}
```

ERROR : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'

Debug item :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPT8R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get data using property.
When you use `new`, it return anonymous object, so you need to work with dynamic object.
once you get value of your dyanmic object `key`, again you need to work with dynamic object `val`.

```
@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var item in @ViewBag.DataGrid)
{
    @:<tr>
    <td>@i</td>
    var val = item.GetType()
           .GetProperty("Key")
           .GetValue(item);

    var PosisiJabatanId = val.GetType()
           .GetProperty("PosisiJabatanId")
           .GetValue(val);

    var AplikasiId = val.GetType()
          .GetProperty("AplikasiId")
          .GetValue(val);

    <td>@PosisiJabatanId</td>
    <td>@AplikasiId</td>

    i = i + 1;
@:</tr>
}
```

[image: you can check value.]

Answer (score 1):

You filled your `ViewBag` with anonymous type value and you cannot cast them in `View`, you should change this line

```
lst.GroupBy(x => new { x.PosisiJabatanId, x.AplikasiId });
```

to

```
lst.GroupBy(x => new MyObject { x.PosisiJabatanId, x.AplikasiId });
```

and cast `ViewBag` to `MyObject` in your `View`

```
@foreach (var item in (MyObject)ViewBag.DataGrid) {...}
```

Comment: `MyObject` error : the type or namespace name 'MyObkect' could not be found

Comment: You should create `MyObject` and use them

Answer (score 0):

Add select on your query like below

```
   lst = db.Database.SqlQuery<GridReportViewModel>(sqlquery).ToList();
        Viewbag.DataGrid = lst.GroupBy(x => new { x.PosisiJabatanId, x.AplikasiId })
            .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Items = g.ToList() });
```

on your view use like below

```
@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var item in @ViewBag.DataGrid)
{
    @:<tr>
        <td>@i</td>
        <td>@item.Key.PosisiJabatanId</td>
        foreach (GridReportViewModel item2 in @item.Items)
        {
            <td>@item2.NilaiKolom</td>
        }
        i = i + 1;
    @:</tr>
}
```

Comment: `item` in second `foreach` error"'object' does not contain a definition for 'Items'" @Mukul